# Convert Glut mouse coordinates to opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I have a screen size of 1000x1000 px and I am trying to attain the opengl coordinates. I understand the OpenGL coordinate system is as follows:

```
(-1,1)     |     (1,1)
           |
 --------(0,0)-------
           |
           |
(-1,-1)    |   (1,-1)

void mouse(int btn, int state, int x, int y){
    float mx = x ;
    float my = y ;
    ox = (mx/1000 -0.5);
    oy = -(my/1000 -0.5);
    switch(btn){
        case GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON:
            if(state==GLUT_DOWN){
                printf("%f\n",mx);
                printf("%f\n",my);
                //p1->setPoint(x, y, 1.0);
            }
            break;
    }

};
```

My window resolution being 1000x1000. The current behavior tracks the mouse but not exactly. It lands close to the mouse and is more accurate when closer to 0,0. I thought I had to change the - 0.5 to -1 but that ended up flipping everything.

Comment: adding the 1- completely offset and reversed my y

Comment: Divide by 500, not 1000

Comment: Thanks I just got that as well by multiplying it by 2.

Comment: That's not the "OpenGL coordinate system." That's Normalized Device Coordinates in general. A lot of different graphics APIs share that space, and it's what you draw in if you don't have any transformation matrices setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void mouse(int btn, int state, int x, int y){
    float mx = x ;
    float my = y ;
    ox = (mx/500-1.0);
    oy = -(my/500 -1.0);
    switch(btn){
        case GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON:
            if(state==GLUT_DOWN){
                printf("%f\n",mx);
                printf("%f\n",my);
            }
            break;
    }

};
```

ox = (glutx/(half of screen x) - 1

oy = -((gluty/(half of screen y) - 1)

Comment: This code will give values between -0.5 and 1.5. You need to subtract 1.0, not 0.5.

Comment: Thanks for the catch I changed it in the description but forgot to change the code